# TYPO3: Override field bodytext to load rte_ckeditor in extension

Tags: typo3, extbase

I'm currently updating a TYPO3 (and the installed custom extensions) from 6.2 to 8.7. The extensions create some custom content elements, build with "extbuilder". Everything is fine so far, but the rte_ckeditor ist not loaded in backend in these content elements. rte_ckeditor is installed and works in standard content elements.

I tried it with the sinple 2nd example "rte_1" here https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/8.7/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Text.html using columnsOverrides. This is my code in file typo3conf/ext/myExt/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php

```
    $GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['myext']['columnsOverrides'] = array(
    'bodytext' => array(
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'enableRichtext' => true,
        )
    )
);
```

In my ext_tables.php the field is loaded with:

```
$TCA['tt_content']['types']['myext_callout']['showitem'] = 'CType, header;Überschrift, subheader;Untertitel, image, bodytext;Beschreibung Preis/Leistung';
```

Do you have an idea, why the editor isn't loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. This is in tt_content.php the correct code:

```
$customFields = [
    'bodytext' => [
        'exclude' => false,
        'l10n_mode' => 'prefixLangTitle',
        'label' => 'Inhalt',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'text',
            'cols' => 40,
            'rows' => 6,
            'enableRichtext' => true
        ],
    ]
];
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns('tt_content',$customFields);
```